# How to open a file or folder from Terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, nautilus

I'd like to know if there is a way to open a file or a folder from terminal?

When I wrote a URL LINK in terminal, it's allows me to open that link on my default browser. So I'd like to do the same with my files and folders.

Eg. When I write "pwd" the path allows me to click and open on Nautilus

It's the inverse of what "nautilus-open-terminal" does.

Comment: Which terminal?

Comment: I'm using gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 3):

In the current directory:

```
nautilus .
```

Some other directory:

```
nautilus /tmp
nautilus "$HOME"
```

etc.

**Edit** As I understand you prefer something to click on, let's start with *making it a URI/URL in the first place* (sic): e.g.

```
echo "file://$PWD"
```

Now you can click the url as ever and nautilus will open there. It isn't foolproof with spaces, special characters etc. although there is a chance that your terminal will magically DoTheRightThing <sup>TM</sup>. Other than 'using' URL's like this, I don't think there is a way.

Comment: Which part of this involves clicking on the path?

Comment: Mmmm. So unexpected I couldn't imagine the OP wanted _that_. Added my idea for that.

Comment: But is there any way to add the "file://" URI Scheme to something, so the bash or the terminal can add the files and folders automatically?

Then when I use PWD and click on the path, nautilus will open?

Comment: Like I said, I don't think so